# Bad Allocation using pointer to classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I've been writing a crude Text Based adventure for practice, but I've run into this problem and I can't figure out how to fix the crashing. I'm afraid this problem is a bit above my skill level, so I'm going to try and get an answer here.

I'm going to try and only post the relevent things.

```
class Location{
public:
Location *ConnectionNorth,
          *ConnectionSouth;
    void ConnectedNorth(Location room){ConnectionNorth = &room;}
    void ConnectedSouth(Location room){ConnectionSouth = &room;}
}
int main(){
  Location roomA;
  Location roomB
  Location *currentRoom;
  roomA.ConnectedNorth(roomB);//room B is connected to A to the North
  roomB.ConnectedSouth(roomA);//room A is connected to B to the South
  currentRoom = &roomA;
while(playing){
 //get input
    if(input == wants to go north)
      currentRoom = currentRoom->ConnectionNorth;
      //tell user they're in room B
    if(input == wants to go south)
      currentRoom = currentRoom->ConnectionSouth;
      //tell user they're in room A
}
```

The annoying part is my code works for room changes about 3 times before crashing, I assume it's because I'm doing something wrong with the pointers, but I lack the knowledge.

Comment: `void ConnectedNorth(Location room)` is incorrect - you want to send in either a reference or a straight up pointer. The code you have now creates a local copy, assigns the pointer and then destructs the local copy, invalidating the pointer.

Comment: This seems more like a question for SO.

Comment: you're not initializing all the pointers. if half the pointers are uninitialized, its no surprise that it eventually crashes.

Comment: +1 for still making text adventures.

Answer (score 0):

```
void ConnectedNorth(Location room){ConnectionNorth = &room;}
```

As soon as this function returns, `room` ceases to exist. So you've saved a parameter to a `Location` that has been destroyed. You probably meant:

```
void ConnectedNorth(Location& room){ConnectionNorth = &room;}
```